Found lost internet archive photo and can't seem to translate it
My boyfriend found this photo, loved the art, however can't seem to translate it. I gave it a shot and I think one word says "god", the font makes it untranslatable through copy and paste, any help? **

That looks like 「神佛控」, but I can't find anything incorporating this phrase.

I would translate 神佛控, in a literal sense, as "Under the control / influence of something Divine or other worldly", as can be seen from the illustration of an other worldly figure, (Grim Reaper), leading a small, innocent boy. It is, to me, not a pleasant image.

"控” an 'ACGN' lingo

“控”源于英文单词complex（情结）的前头（con），日本人借用过来（コン），按照日语语法形成“某某控”的语言景观重构。


“控” originated from the first part of the English word complex (con), which was borrowed into Japanese （コン）, According to Japanese usage, XX Con = XX complex (obsessive of XX)

My guess is 神佛控 (a Chinese phrase) implies "one with a gods complex" (someone obsessed with gods-related myths and stories)

THANK YOU, I've been trying to figure this out for a long time!

Thanks to @kyc's comment below, from which I now learned that the word "仏" is a "俗字(古)" of, and used by Japanese for, "佛".
仏 (いろいろな書体) -


I guess the words are "神仙控".

My previous guess was wrong, it should be correct to "神仏控".

I think people say it’s 佛 because it’s 仏.
